# Transform any signed char type into an unsigned one

Tags: c++, templates, char, wchar

```
template< typename charT >
struct serializer
{
    /* ... */
private:
    std::basic_string< charT > base64_encode( unsigned charT * bytes, unsigned length );
};
```

I would like the private member function to take an *unsigned* whatever-char-type. If charT is char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, I want the signature to be *unsigned that*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is by usage of [`std::make_unsigned`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/make_unsigned/), which works for any integral type:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type convert(T const& input)
{
    return static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(input);
}
```

Using this in your class becomes fairly ugly when used directly, so we will add a type alias:

```
template< typename charT >
struct serializer
{
    typedef typename ::std::make_unsigned<charT>::type ucharT;
    /* ... */
private:
    std::basic_string< ucharT > base64_encode( ucharT * bytes, unsigned length );
};
```

Comment: It should be only `ucharT* bytes` in the function signature, without `unsigned` - since the type `ucharT` is already unsigned now.